# When does the day start?

Tags: support

I generally sign in at least once a day, sometimes late in the evening or night.
Sometimes it shows I missed a day.

Perhaps this question would more appropriately ask, where does the day start?

Is Stack Exchange on EST?

Or perhaps it just doesn't know my local time zone?

Any ideas?

Comment: there is a an MSO tag dedicated to questions about this: [consecutive-days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consecutive-days) "For questions about how consecutive days are counted, how the consecutive-day-class badges are awarded, and other support on consecutive days."

Answer (score 10):

The Stack Exchange day starts at midnight UTC.

This means that it starts at 7:00 pm EST (assuming you're not on daylight savings).

Comment: Also, current UTC time is shown in the profile dropdown when you hover over your name on the top bar.

Answer (score -1):

There is, however, inconsistency... on my List of Accounts it is currently showing all of them as visited **Today** (06:05utc) which I know not to be true, although I have visited them within the last 24 hours.

This may (still be) be Today in another time zone...?

Comment: What were you expecting it to say?

Comment: Yesterday... since I hadn't visited any of them today!

Comment: Was hoping you'd be a bit more specific. As an example, if you're on the West Coast of the US at 7PM on a Thursday, that makes it 2AM UTC on Friday. Since you didn't list details like your local timezone, you'll have to do the conversion yourself. As far as SE is concerned, you live on Greenwich Mean Time, or UTC, or GMT+0... same timezone as London. So when it says you visited "today" and the last time you visited was late at night in the US, the date is recorded as your tomorrow. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm in UK, so I would expect "today" to be today.  This morning, *this* is the first page I've visited on any SE site, yet all my accounts that I visited yesterday are showing as "Last visited today" already

Comment: Ah, if you're in the UK then you're lucky, living in the center of the world and all and avoiding those pesky GMT to local time conversions. :) ....  Are you visiting your profile page from another account?  If not, then when you visit the site, the data is updating, and it's showing you that you last visited... well... right now. :)  Tomorrow, try logging out of your accounts and *then* go visit your profile page. I bet it will look more like what you expect.